# jquery: physically paste html code inside div (and transform code later)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tl;dr:

> How to put a html code stored in jquery string inside div
>   (physically)? Then (again) modify him by js.

I have a simple code:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $('#someDIV').empty();
    $('#someDIV').innerHTML($login)

});
```

Everything works fine, but code from `$login` must be in `#someDIV` like when we write this "manually". Now, he is somewhere, but no in div :)

Now in html code:

```
<div id="someDIV"></div>
```

After some magic changes:

```
<div id="someDIV">blablablabla (form $login)</div>
```

Why I want do this? After "some magic changes" I have to modifying that code by js.

Comment: `innerHTML` is javascript property. You need to use `html()` to change html content of element in jquert. Use `$('#someDIV').html($login)` instead.

Comment: still the same problem. In "view-source" mode I have only div, without code

Comment: Do you have div with ID as per `$('#someDIV')`?

Comment: @Sokołow You just can't do that. JS changes are temporary...... for that you have to write your html from server instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says:

> innerHTML is a DOM method but you have a jquery object.

So, either use dom element or bind the jquery method to it.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $('#someDIV').html($login);
});
```

And you don't need to use `.empty()` as you are already overwriting everything in the target div.

Comment: I still gettnig blank div (<div id="someDIV"></div>) in view-source mode.

The problem is, that HTML code from $login I want again transform by js (after put in to div).

Comment: @Sokołow You just can't do that. JS changes are temporary...... for that you have to write your html from server instead.

Comment: You can transform it again any way you want but you have to add this requirement in the question too.

Comment: Done. Later I want to add class in some place (in this code), in other add image - like in "normal", html code.

Comment: For that you can use `.append(), .prepend() etc` or something like this can be done too: `var $withImg = $('#someDIV').html()+$img; $('#someDIV').html($withImg);`